# IBM Mobile First Platform - Bypass validity check of the host certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

How can i bypass validity check of the host certificate in IBM mobile first platform(MFP) iOS SDK ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Instead of bypassing why not use http ?

Comment: This is for a testing purpose .. i just want to accept all kinds of certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bypass validating the certificate in IBM Mobilefirst Platform iOS SDK as this defeats the purpose of using secured connection via `HTTPS` protocol. Alternatively, you can use `HTTP` protocol if you wish to not use client certificates.